# ichol as cholinc replacement: nonpositive pivot

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, matrix-factorization

In Matlab 2012 the `cholinc` command is marked as obsolete. The warning message says it is to be replaced by `ichol`. Until now I used `cholinc(A,droptol)`, typically with `droptol=1E-15`. In the new version I tried to use `ichol(A,struct('droptol',droptol,'type','ict'))`, which works most of the time, but sometimes I get a warning message

```
Error using ichol
Encountered nonpositive pivot.
```

Is this a fundamental problem (i.e. a problem `cholinc` also had but didn't report) or is there a way to make `ichol` behave in the way `cholinc` formerly did?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error indicates that the incomplete Cholesky method has broken down, which is a well-known possibility for symmetric positive-definite, but not diagonally dominant matrices.  That is, even if a matrix has a (complete) Cholesky factorization, it may not have an incomplete Cholesky factorization.

`cholinc` doesn't suffer breakdown because it is not a true incomplete Cholesky.  Rather, it calls `luinc` with no pivoting, throws out L and then scales the resulting U to obtain a kind of incomplete Cholesky factor (see the doc for `cholinc`, first paragraph of the Algorithms section).  You can obtain a factor very similar to that from `cholinc` by using `ilu` (note that `luinc` is also obsolete).

```
[L,U] = ilu(A,struct('type','ilutp','droptol',droptol,'thresh',0));
R = diag(sqrt(abs(diag(U))))\U;
% Essentially the same as cholinc.
```

Use of `ichol` is strongly encouraged, if possible.  Note that you can use the `'diagcomp'` option to try to prevent breakdown in your factorization, but finding an effective parameter `alpha` may require experimentation.  See the doc for `ichol` for an example.  When `ichol` does not breakdown, it tends to be much faster as it exploits symmetry.  Also, it tends to produce sparser factors than `cholinc` which results in faster application of the factor as a preconditioner, which can mean faster solution times with `pcg`.  For example,

```
M = delsq(numgrid('L',200));
tic; R1 = ichol(M,struct('type','ict','droptol',1e-2,'shape','upper')); toc
% Elapsed time is 0.013809 seconds.
nnz(R1)
% ans = 145632
tic; R = cholinc(M,1e-2); toc
% Elapsed time is 0.167155 seconds.
nnz(R)
% ans = 173851
```

To be fair, the timing of `cholinc` above includes time to dispatch the warning, but a tic/toc of just a single warning shows that time to be in the noise of this particular computation.

Finally, note that by default, `ichol` references the lower triangle of the input matrix and returns a lower triangular factor.  Preferring lower triangular factors can give a notable performance increase:

```
tic; L = ichol(M,struct('type','ict','droptol',1e-2)); toc
% Elapsed time is 0.008895 seconds.
```

As a final remark, the drop tolerance of 1e-15 you reference above is very small.  If that is the kind of tolerance you are using, you might be better off using a complete factorization such as `chol`, `ldl`, or `lu`.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! I will try what you're suggesting when I find the time. Just a couple comments: 1) I tried 'diagcomp' but it later turned out that in some cases it gave incorrect (= not what I needed) results for the `alpha` I initially chose. 2) The drop tolerance of `1E-15` I chose because 'cholinc' worked already with such small values whereas `chol` didn't for the matrices in question. I just figured smaller is better. Don't know if that's true in all cases...?

Comment: It sounds like your matrix is semidefinite, or nearly so.  Smaller is better, (as in closer to exact) but it may be much slower.  You might try preordering your matrix (use `amd` or `symrcm`) to get sparser factors (less memory and computation) and therefore better performance.  Separately, you might try using `ldl` instead of `chol`.  `ldl` is designed for indefinite matrices so it is more computationally expensive than `chol`, but less so than `lu`.

Comment: Now that you say it, yes the matrices I consider are sometimes semidefinite! Again, thanks for your very helpful comments, will try them out tomorrow!